# SpringJUnit4ClassRunner context configuration with Resource values

Tags: java, spring, junit-runner, spring-boot-test

I am trying to configure Spring, Junit and Hibernate (to enable `@Autowire` annotation for our test cases). My current setup is this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml",
})
public class UserManagementServiceTest {...}
```

However, the initialization fails with

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file: java.naming.factory.initial
```

We've defined various credentials in `context.xml` files which are picked up by tomcat when running the application. The structure is as below

```
<Context>
    <Resource name="abc/abcManager"
                auth="Container"
                type="path.to.file"
                factory="org.apache.naming.factory.BeanFactory"
                attr1="asas"
                attr2="asda"/>
</Context>
```

These attributes are then picked up using `InitialContext` class.

How do I configure the above functionality for our test cases?

Adding the `context.xml` file to `ContextConfiguration` gives the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 10; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Context'.
```